# How do I get the sum of the Counts of nested Lists in a Dictionary without using foreach?

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I want to get the total number of items in the `List`s in the following `Dictionary`:

```
Dictionary<int, List<string>> dd = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>() {
    {1, new List<string> {"cem"}},
    {2, new List<string> {"cem", "canan"}},
    {3, new List<string> {"canan", "cenk", "cem"}}
};

// This only returns an enumerated array.
var i = (from c in dd
         select c.Value.Count).Select(p=>p);
```

Comment: You want a total count? In the case of the example 6?

Comment: yes. I want to totalk count of every item of dictionarys list item count.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I believe this will get you the count you want efficiently and clearly. Under the hood it has to iterate through the lists, but to get a total count, there is no way to avoid this.

```
var i = dd.Values.Sum(x => x.Count);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var i = dd.Values.SelectMany(v => v).Count();
```

Answer (score 2):

Total count of all list items:

```
dd.SelectMany(i => i.Value).Count();
```

`List` containing individual list counts:

```
dd.Select(i => i.Value.Count).ToList()
```

Comment: Good answer using with SelectMany.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
var l = dd.Select(i => new {i, i.Value.Count});
```

Comment: ohhh didnt see that last comment... oh well

Answer (score 0):

var total = dictionary.Sum(x => x.Value.Count());